# Building an Website (in node.js) and an API in .net core 2.1 with jwt. How to connect them?

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am building an Website and API for a school project.
The website is being made in `Node.js`while the API is built in `.netCore version 2.1` with `JWT authentication`.
The API is working properly and if i use `Postman` to access the api with the token it works, but how i do it with my website? 
I will use the api information to show it using `JavaScript`. 
After some research i didn't found anything.
Any idea how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if using Node.js as a client application is a good approach since it is more commonly used as a backend server. I would suggest you use some js Frontend Framework such as Angular or React.